# Segmentation fault (core dumped) while declaring vectors

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I have been trying to use vectors, but whenever I declare them globally , I get a segmentation fault (core dumped) error. But when I specify a size on the vector I declared, the error no longer occurs. If dynamic allocation occurs in vector, then why is there a need of giving a size and what is this error? Someone please kindly explain.

The code is for implementation of an adjacency list (graph) using vector:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
typedef vector< int > vi;
typedef vector< vi > vii;
vii adjlist;
int main()
{
      int n,m; // no. of vertices and no. of edges
      cin>>n>>m;
      for(int i =0;i<m;i++)
       {
          int p,q;
          cin>>p>>q;
          adjlist[p].push_back(q);
          adjlist[q].push_back(p);
        }
       for(int i =0;i<n;i++)
       {
            cout<<i;
            for(int j =0; j< (int)adjlist[i].size();++i)
             {
                      cout<<"_>"<<adjlist[i][j];
              }
            cout<<endl;
        }
   return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Why did you tag this as `C` when vector is a `C++` class?  Also, please show your code.

Comment: Your question reads "I wrote some code and it doesn't work. Please explain". No code -> no help!

Answer (score 0):

`std::vector` does not automatically resize when you index into it. You need to manually resize it with `resize`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to resize you vector before using like `vector[i]`. for this you can use `resize` function defined in `stl vector class`.

e.x.

for `n x m` vector use `vector_name.resize(n,vector<int>(m))`.